# What's the meaning of "Front" in "Pareto-Optimal Front"?

Tags: optimization

I'm reading a paper about **Multi-Objective Optimization Problem**. I understand **Optimal in Pareto sense**, and I even know what is **Pareto-Optimal Front** somehow. But I can't find a relationship between the word **Front** and the concept. So, what's the meaning of this word in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is sort of short for "frontier" (as in boundary between one thing and another.)  The two canonical examples would be a [weather front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_front) (the boundary between a cold airmass and a warm airmass) and a [military front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_%28military%29) (the boundary between the areas controlled by a pair of belligerent armies).

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you very much. Indeed, visually, the set of objective vectors corresponding to Pareto optimals, is a boundary for all possible objective vectors.