# Pseudo code algorithm for beauty contestant question

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Say beauty pageants are judged based on 3 criteria: 1) Appearance 2) Personality 3) Talent. A contestant $C$ will beat another contestant $C'$ if she gets higher scores in ALL THREE of the criteria.

There are $n$ girls competing. Contestant $C_i$ is "Model Material" if $C_i$ is not beat by any other contestant $C_j$. Pretend you're the announcer and you have a collection of tuples: $(A_i, P_i, T_i)$ for $i = 1, 2,...,n$

The $i$th tuple contains the appearance, personality, and talent rating for $C_i$ (higher scores are better). Return a list of the "Model Material" contestants in in $O(n\log{n})$ time.

Given a data structure w/ a set $E$ of ints that, given an int $a$, --- (1) tells if a is in $E$ (2) finds smallest value > $a$ or largest value < $a$ in $E$ (3) inserts or removes a from $E$ in $O(\log{|E|})$ time.

I am trying to write pseudo-code for this algorithm but am lost trying to think of a correct algorithm that also runs in $O(n\log{n})$ time. I thought about starting initially with the $A_1$, $P_1$, and $T_1$ values for the first contestant, and if another contestant has a higher score in each category, remove the current tuple and replace it with the higher tuple, then repeat this process starting with a different contestant each time, but that's obviously not $O(n\log{n})$, and probably doesn't even work.

(This question was from my algorithms professor, and I can't find it online or in our textbook)

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE.  What's the context in which you encountered this problem?  Did you find it in a programming contest?  Textbook?  Course exercise?  Can you edit the question to provide information on the source of the problem?

Comment: It looks like you may have inadvertently created two accounts.  I encourage you to register your account and create a password login, and [merge your two accounts](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  This will ensure you retain access to your question and can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the [Pareto-optimal front](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/25794/755) in 3D space.  This is a [well-studied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) problem.

In 2D, there are $O(n \log n)$ time algorithms: see, e.g., [What are some interesting applications of the skyline problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41382/755), [An online algorithm to find the Pareto frontier elements](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52201/755), [minimum subset of dominating 2D points](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44670/755).

In 3D, life is more complicated, but apparently it is still possible to solve this in $O(n \log n)$ using fancy methods.  See the following paper:

[On Finding the Maxima of a Set of Vectors](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/211/201/on_the_computational_complexity_of_finding_the_maxima_of_a.pdf).  H.T. Kung, F. Luccio, F.P.Preparata.  Journal of the ACM, vol 22 no 4, Oct 1975, pp.469--476.